# elements are not centered aligned inside the wrapper and when I set the width of the wrapper it goes out of the browser width..any solution?

Tags: html, css

Elements inside `.wrapper` are not centered aligned and after assigning width to `.wrapper`, it's showing a horizontal scrollbar.

```css
#footer {
  width:100%;
}
#footer .wrapper{
  background:red;
  margin:0 auto;
  position:relative;
  width: 1024px;
  height: 192px;
  font-size:a
}
#footer .wrapper .col {
  width: 20%;
  height: 192px;
  background: green; 
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<footer id="footer">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="col right-list">
    </div>
    <div class="col middle-list">
    </div>
    <div class="col left-list">
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Any suggestions as to why this is happening?

Comment: please provide more information regarding what you are expecting to see and how this differs from what you are currently seeing

Comment: used `max-width` instead of `width` for  `.wrapper` and and add `text-align:center` to align center div

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer .wrapper{
  background:red;
  margin:0 auto;
  position:relative;
  max-width: 1024px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 192px;
  font-size:a
}
```

you may not set a determined width

Comment: sorry I might misunderstand what you want

Answer (score 0):

Were you looking for something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/3ux7bdpf/

```
#footer {
  width:100%;
}
#footer .wrapper{
  background:red;
  margin:0 auto;
  position:relative;
  height: 192px;
  font-size:a
}
#footer .wrapper .col {
  width: 20%;
  margin-right:10%;
  height: 192px;
  background: green; 
  display: inline-block;
}
#footer .wrapper .col:first-child {
  margin-left:10%;
}
#footer .wrapper .col:last-child {
  margin-right:0;
}
```

Comment: yessss it worked perfectly thanks , do you know how to make it responsive? great thanx in advance

Comment: It is responsive now in the sense that the three columns will expand/shrink as the screen gets wider/narrower. If you wanted the columns to stay the same width, then you wouldn't use 20% width on the columns. For any other responsive styles, you can do that using @media queries. You should mark this as the answer to your original question though.

Answer (score 0):

Its is simple. **Why you are assigning fixed width to .wrapper**

Just put **width: 100%;** or any width you want respective of footer in **%.**

**Instead Assign Max-width to it.** So if browser size is more than max-width than it will adjust accoring to your max-width.

```css
#footer {
  width:100%;
}
#footer .wrapper{
  max-width: 1024px;
  background:red;
  margin:0 auto;
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 192px;
  text-align: center;
}
#footer .wrapper .col {
  width: 20%;
  height: 192px;
  background: green; 
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<footer id="footer">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="col right-list">
    </div>
    <div class="col middle-list">
    </div>
    <div class="col left-list">
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: glad to your answer but I want green elements to be centered not on right or left thank you :)

Comment: your green boxes are already responsive as you have given width in %. If you want to reduce height according to screen size then use media-query. And if ans is helpful to you. Then accept it.